# Should I bargain my internship offer?

Tags: research-process, research-undergraduate, salary, internship

I have been searching for an internship for over a year now, and have finally and successfully gotten a job offer. The interview went very well, from the time I contacted HR, to the time I got 'hired' (manager wanted me on the spot), it took about a week total. I googled what their intern salaries are, and what they offered me is $1.5 lower than what I found. However, I have no experience in the industry, all I have is research and another part-time job, and most importantly, this was the only company at which I was able to receive an interview. It does not say in the offer whether the salary is negotiable or not, but a huge part of me says not to bargain, because the offer does say my pay will increase as I complete more schooling. Any and all recommendations are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what industry it is, which might be helpful.  You should also clarify this to establish the relation to academia, so that your post isn't closed.

I can say that in my internship experience involving think tanks, the salaries for interns, such as they are, are pretty well set by policy.  One place I was at had just a single rate all interns were paid, no questions asked.  The other had two tiers for interns, one paid slightly better, but which tier it was was dictated by the position in the budget, not by negotiation.

So based on that I would say no, don't negotiate.  For better or for worse, there tends to be a line of people waiting to get internships and most of them don't have much to differentiate them from the field (which is why they're going for internships and not full jobs).  So it's likely that the criteria they used to select you is fairly thin, particularly with no experience in the field.

Plus with nothing to fall back on your bargaining position is pretty weak, even if they don't know they're your only interview.